# Not getting Buttons updated using MVVM and Autofac in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, autofac

I'm building a small app that is based on MVVM and uses Autofac as a dependency injector.

I've created the VMBase which all the ViewModels depends from and I'm also using VMLocator to inject all the dependencies (using Autofac as stated before).

```
public class VMLocator
{
    IContainer container;

    public VMLocator()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<VMRetrieveInfo>();
        container = builder.Build();
    }

    public VMRetrieveInfo RetrieveInfoViewModel
    {
        get { return container.Resolve<VMRetrieveInfo>(); }
    }
}
```

Got a DelegateCommand class that handles Raises of CanExecute:

```
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
            this.CanExecuteChanged(null, new EventArgs());
    }
```

My problem comes when I try to put a button using DelegateCommand class that changes its state using a CanExecute method which returns a variable that is changed when I press another button. 
Changing the value of the variable doesn't seem to launch any event that changes the CanExecute result (the CanExecute method is not even called) and I'm pretty lost.

```
    public ICommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get { return navigateCommand; }
    }

    public void NavigateCommandExecute()
    {

    }

    public bool NavigateCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return canCallWS;
    }
```

Running a similar app without dependency injection (Autofac) has worked for me before.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DelegateCommand class you have a CanExecuteChanged event, the same way you did a RaisePropertyChanged method to launch the PropertyChanged in your ViewModel base, you need to do a RaiseCanExecuteChanged method in your DelegateCommand class to launch the CanExecuteChanged event when you change the condition...

In WPF we have a CommandManager who makes this job for us without need to launch the event. In Windows Phone we need to launch the event. This is not an autofac or DI issue, is the way command can execute works in Silverlight/Windows Phone.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Josue! a pleasure you've been the one answering ;-)

Comment: Hi! Great, now where you update the canCallWS variable/property, call the RaiseCanExecuteChanged of the DelegateCommand you want to update CanExecute status and voila! it just need to work....

Comment: But shoudn't it be an automatic call? I think I remember it being called whenever you change the variable...

Comment: Yes, in WPF, not in Silverlight/Windows Phone :(